# fovea in app purchae plugin/several database entries

Tags: ios, angular, laravel, cordova, in-app-purchase

I have a problem on the in app purchase cordova plugin by fovea.

I am kinda confused.
What I want to do, is that when the user chooses a product (monthly subscription), I do what I need to do, process payment and all that jazz, and when everything is done, I save an entry in my database, to indicate that the user is subscribed (and some more info).

However, when I use it, I see that I have not one but at least 10 saved entries. For same user, same product.

I have no idea why it does that. So I guess something is wrong with my code. As I use Sandbox for testing IOS side, sometimes the pop up just doesn't appear (where you need to enter your password and confirm your purchase), and yet I have 10/20 entries saved in my database (I put that bit of code when product is owned, then in the .finished event).

Can someone help me?

Here is the code

```
let produit = null;
if (!(window as any).store) {
    alert('Store indispo');
}

this.store.register({
    id: this.valeurEnvoi.app,
    alias: 'abonnement',
    type: store.PAID_SUBSCRIPTION,
});
console.log(this.valeurEnvoi.app);
this.store.refresh();

this.store.ready( () => {
    produit = this.store.get(this.valeurEnvoi.app);
    this.envoiLogs('récupération du produit', 'NO ID');

    if (produit.canPurchase) {
        this.store.order(produit);
    }
});
this.store.refresh();
// this.store.manageSubscriptions();

this.store.when(produit).updated( (p) =>  {
    if (p.owned) {
    } else {
    }
});
this.store.refresh();
console.log(this.store.log);

this.store.error( error => {
    this.testLog = error.message;
    alert('erreur: ' + error.code + ' message: ' + error.message);
});


this.store.when(produit).approved( (order) => {
    order.finish();
});
this.store.refresh();

this.store.when(produit).finished( (order) => {
    const test = this.store.findInLocalReceipts(produit);
    alert(test.transactionId);
    this.confirmerAchatMobile();
});
```

Also, If I could have some pointer to get the transactionID, that would be great! Thank you!
If you see any strange stuff, let me know, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the repo. refresh() appears to be deprecated:

```
         /**
         * @deprecated - use store.initialize(), store.update() or store.restorePurchases()
         */
        refresh() {
            throw new Error("use store.initialize() or store.update()");
        }
```

source: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/www/store.js

Also, from a comment I infer that the transactions are replayed if you call refresh multiple times, could that cause your issue?: `Notice that all previous transactions will be replayed if you call store.refresh() a second time in the lifetime of your app.`
source: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/1298

There are quite a few (109) issues on the git repo. So I think you might find your answer there. If not, I'd create an issue there, the maintainers are probably more likely to have an answer for you.

Comment: thank you ! The several refresh were a test, I had one previously and yet had this problem already. I am going to ask them, thanks a lot !